# Is there a way to get multiple results from PHP Geocoder for ambiguous locations as default?

Tags: php, api, google-maps, geocoding

I tried searching for a location which I knew should return multiple results i.e. "Paris" and I got only Paris, France as a result. I also tried certain towns, villages, that I know exist in several places, and also partial names but every time I would only get a single result, often the wrong one.

Is there a way to get a list of matching results?

I am using PHP Geocoder, but Google Geocoding API knowledge on this would also be useful.

I googled the hell out of this, read PHP Geocoder documentation, read up on Region Biasing in google docs, and  but all I could find is how to get region specific results, as opposed to region unspecific, or unspecific in any way, which is what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

From the keyboard of the lovely **toin0u** of Geocoder PHP:

"
The Geocoder ~2.x uses a ResultFactory. The DefaultResultFactory takes into account only the first result. If you need mutilple results you need to use the setter:

```
// ...
Geocoder::setResultFactory(new \Geocoder\Result\MultipleResultFactory);
// ...
```

"

So an example would be:

```
Geocoder::setResultFactory(new \Geocoder\Result\MultipleResultFactory);
return Geocoder::geocode('Paris, France');
```

And voila, multiple results!

(Also, by using Google Geocoder API I got multiple results, no problem. )